# Redstone torches spasming out?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

In my server when i place redstone torches and work on something else while on the same chunk the redstone torch can sometimes flicker even when on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you encounter the same bug as mentionned on this topic :

[Fixing permanently dead redstone torches](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/28674/fixing-permanently-dead-redstone-torches-in-minecraft/29214#29214)

Which answer was :

> [Known bugs on Minecraft Wiki #Redstone Torches](http://minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Known_bugs#Redstone_Torches)
>
> This is a know bug, all you can do is restarting your game. It happens
>   sometimes on random blocks, and it will never work again on that block
>   until you restart. It happens both on single and multiplayer, we hope
>   it will be fixed on 1.8